# How to delete duplicate values from multiple columns in a spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am stuck with something and need your help. I have a spreadsheet with 6326 Columns and 50 Rows. What I want to do is to remove duplicate from each column and calculate the number of unique elements and tally with other columns

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Columns("G:G").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$G$1:$G$50").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Range("G1").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try looping through your entire range if your columns are contiguous.

```
With Sheets("SheetName")
    For i = 0 To 6325
        .Range("G1:G50").Offset(0, i).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    Next
End With
```

Suppress screen updating cause this will take a while and is costly in terms of speed.